# Android Zxing after scanned barcode can't launch activity

Tags: android, zxing

I am following this https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent tutorial to do a scan barcode feature in my apps. I am able to scan the barcode but after scan it back to the first screen instead of ReserveBook.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    context = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.barcode_scan);
    scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.scan_button){
        System.out.println("START SCAN");
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
            requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {

        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        mDbHelper.open();
        BookController bc = new BookController(mDbHelper.open());
        System.out.println(scanContent);
        String bookID = bc.getBookIDByBarcode(scanContent);
        System.out.println(bookID);
        intent= new Intent(context, ReserveBook.class);
        intent.putExtra("BookID", bookID);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```